# Lose the list values when navigating away from page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic4

So I'm storing a list of IItineraries in a private variable that I'm assigning on ngOnInit with the following:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.dataSvc.getItineraries().subscribe(res => {
      this.itineraries = res;
    });
    console.log('logged in user add itin page', this.itineraries);
  }
```

```html
                <ion-list>
                  <div *ngFor="let itinerary of itineraries">
                    <ion-card class="itinerary-module">
                      <ion-card-content>
                        <div>
                          <h2>{{itinerary.startDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}} - {{itinerary.endDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h1>{{itinerary.destination}}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h2>{{itinerary.tripDetails}}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chip" *ngFor="let activity of itinerary.activities">
                          <label> {{ activity }} </label>
                        </div>
                      </ion-card-content>
                    </ion-card>
                  </div>
                </ion-list>
```

It's fine on the initial page load...the values are displayed but when I navigate away from the page and then back it's blank and the values aren't displayed until I close and re-open the app.

Comment: we don't know what `getItineraries()` method does...

Comment: Use a behavior subject to have the initial data upon subscribing. In your service you can store and update the latest data in a class member and have the behavior subject emit that as the initial value upon new subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are in a case of cold Subject Observable started but "not cooling down", i.e. not completing, and not emitting new values.

In your case, it means that when you navigate back to your page, your `getItineraries()` service method new call very probably gives you the same reference of Observable as the first time. It has already started emitting, since you subscribed to it the first time.

But now you will not get any assignment into your `itineraries` component property until the Observable emits a new value, which may never happen depending on what it does internally.

In that case, you have many possible solutions: try properly unsubscribing when the component is destroyed, rework your Observable into a Behavior Subject...

If you use it only in your template, you can also directly call it there with the async pipe. The template will automatically unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.

Comment: I fixed it by replacing this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H20l9ofyR54
with this one
https://javebratt.com/ionic-firebase-tutorial-list/